# .live working but .on not working

Tags: jquery, dialog, live

If I am using .live debugger goes inside block and it opens up the dialog,but if i use .on it doesn't. Why?

```
 $('#btnCreateNewSet').live("click", function (e) {
                debugger;
                e.preventDefault();
                if(e.handled === true) return false;
                e.handled = true;

                $("#divDialog")
                     .dialog({modal:true})
                  .load("/ClaimAuditAdmin/CreateNewSet");

                return false;
            });

    $('#btnCreateNewSet').on("click", function (e) {
                debugger;
                e.preventDefault();
                if(e.handled === true) return false;
                e.handled = true;

                $("#divDialog")
                     .dialog({modal:true})
                  .load("/ClaimAuditAdmin/CreateNewSet");

                return false;
            });
```

Comment: which version of jquery are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

I think your element is dynamically added to DOM, so you need to use event delegation using `.on()`. Instead of `document` head you should try use any other container that exists in the DOM at any given time to delegate the event to `#btnCreateNewSet`. If that is not the case, probably your handler is not under document.ready `$(function(){....});`

Try this:

```
  $(document).on("click", '#btnCreateNewSet' , function (e) {

                e.preventDefault();
                if(e.handled === true) return false;
                e.handled = true;

                $("#divDialog")
                     .dialog({modal:true})
                  .load("/ClaimAuditAdmin/CreateNewSet");

                return false;
            });
```

Also make sure your version of jquery supports `.on()` (available from 1.7).

Comment: Then something else might be going on. DO you think you can replicate in fiddle. also before your event registration just place an `alert($('#btnCreateNewSet').length)`